# Is there any text-based html rendering engine working with curl-php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, curl

When I interact webpages with PHP cURL, in some pages, I have to use regular expressions if AJAX and JavaScript are used in that page.

So are there any suggestions for rendering HTML pages and getting that text-based rendered HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about doing server-side rendering of the page, i.e a headless browser. AFAIK there is nothing like this implemented in php. However there is in c++ - Nokia/Trolltech's Qt, and there's a python api too - PyQt. Qt is an entire GUI toolkit, but a fully-specced DOM renderer is included (webkit I believe), and you don't need to actually render to screen. Or in java there is HTMLUnit, or you could use Selenium, which is basically running Firefox as a server-side process.